# Let f : [0, 1] → [0,1]. Suppose that f attains every value between 0 and 1 in the interval [0, 1], then f is continuous in the interval [0, 1].

Tags: calculus, continuity

First , Im not quit sure what f : [0, 1] → [0,1] means.

Second, why do I need to know that f attains every value between 0 and 1 in the interval [0, 1]? How this informaton helps me?

I tried to read about it in my Professor lecture notes and serched online but couldnt find any answer.
thank you

Comment: The statement in the title is obviously false

Comment: Re your first sentence: The notation $f\colon A\to B$ means that $f$ is a function from the set $A$ (domain) to the set $B$ (co-domain). Here, both the domain $A$ and the co-domain $B$ are the closed interval $[0,1]=\{\,x\in\Bbb R\mid 0\le x\le 1\,\}$

Answer (score 3):

the statement in the title is false. Consider the function $f(x)=2x,$ $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $f(x)=0, x \in (\frac{1}{2},1]$. $f(x)$ attain all the values in beteween 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2):

f : [0, 1] → [0,1] simply means that f is a function that MUST map ALL values in the domain [0, 1] (or else the definition of a function is violated) to [0, 1], since f attains all values in [0, 1].

Other than that, as pointed out by others, the title is incorrect.